# How to fix: Angular Apollo-Client returning an array instead of an id

Tags: angular, apollo-client

I have a problem with my apollo client I'm using in my angular-application. I'm calling an graphQL-Query which returns me the following:

```
account: {id: 1}
accountId: 1
contact: {id: 1}
contactId: 1
id: 23
notes: null
resultId: null
stepId: 1
subject: "testsubject"
```

I see this result in the browsers developer tools (result preview of the call)
So far so good, but the appolo-client returns this:

```
account: {id: 1}
accountId: 1
contact: {id: 1}
contactId: 1
id: {id: {…}, notes: null, stepId: 1, subject: "testsubject", resultId: null, …}
notes: null
resultId: null
stepId: 1
subject: "testsubject"
```

I searched the net for this problem, but it seems that I'm the only one with this, trying the solutions of nearly similar problems didn't solve anything.

Disabling cache didn't solve it

```
      this.apollo.create({
        link: from([this.logoutLink, this.authMiddleware, graphQLDataLink]),
        cache:  new InMemoryCache({
          addTypename: false
        }),
        defaultOptions: {
          query: {
            fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'
          }
        }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

i found the problem. I called 2 querys in one method, and i shadowed the result. Here is the simplyfied method:

callGQLQuery(query1).then(result => {
  ...some code
  callGQLQuery(query2).then(result => {
    => the result here had this error i described, changing the 2nd result in result2 
    solved it
  })
})